# Не импортируется сторонний модуль в Buildozer (Python, Kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

При сборке в *.apk я использовал сторонний модуль pycbrf

Я модуль установил и вставил в проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from pycbrf.toolbox import ExchangeRates
```

А также вставил в init файл(buildozer.spec):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё собралось, но при установке *.apk приложение не открывается.

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: `при установке *.apk приложение не открывается` -> `Не импортируется модуль Buildozer`, а разве не через `buildozer` получаются `apk`? Приложение просто не открывается или есть какие-либо ошибки?

Comment: Оно открывается, появляется изображение с "Loading" и приложение сразу закрывается.

Comment: Пробовали запускать `hello world` -- приложение с одним элементом? Мб проблема с `pycbrf`, мб исключение где происходит, а вы его не ловите

Comment: В том и проблема,что без pycbrf всё работает, а с pycbrf - нет.
Но мне pycbrf нужен для парсинга курса валют.

Comment: Добавьте try/except вокруг `from ... import ...` и смотрите ошибку. Я бы рекомендовал добавить `sys.excepthook` до кода (там вместо QMessageBox вставьте другой: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c434c2dfac74fb5d98b693b8b47b1298d1ee2a2e/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L35). Еще, приложите кусок кода с импортом и кусок файлом настройки, скриншоты неудобны для кода

Comment: При сборке, пока заметил это:


`lld not found, linking without it. Consider installing lld if linker errors occur.
`

Comment: @gil9red при try/except исключение не выбросилось и файл так и не токрывается

Comment: @lev145 Подскажите, у вас решилась эта проблема? В чем было дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливаете на компьютер [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb), подключаете по USB смартфон к компьютеру, запускаете на компьютере терминал, вводите команду `abd logcat | grep python`, запускаете на смартфоне свое приложение, в консоли смотрите лог ошибок.